# Can someone please explain me what does this log statement mean?

Tags: php, apache, access-log

I've a website developed using PHP.

I encountered one major issue on my website, a security breach. So I  checked the access logs of apache present at location "**/var/log/apache2/access.log**" on server.

I got following log which caused the error but I'm not able to understand what does each part of this log means. Can some one please give me step-by-step explanation of the below log?

**70.39.61.42 - - [12/Jul/2015:17:05:12 +0000] "POST /user/register/javascript.void(0)/index.php?do=/user/register/ HTTP/1.1" 302 398 "http://www.mywebsite.com/user/register/javascript.void(0)" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"**

Actually this is the request which has created a major issue on my website. But I'm not able to figure out what parameters that request contained and what was the response, etc., etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That 'error' code is signifying that your request is being redirected. You don't happen to have a site built on MVC or something similar where everything is being directed through an over-zealous `index.php` that might be changing the request do you?

Comment: At 17:05:12 GMT on 12th July this year, an HTTP 1.1 POST request was received from 70.39.61.42 for url user/register/javascript.void(0)/index.php?do=/user/register. The server returned a 302 status (a redirect)

Comment: @MarkBaker:Actually my issue is invalid users got registered even after appying server side validations. I'm not getting how did it bypass the validations.

Comment: @DanielWaghorn: Actually my issue is invalid users got registered even after appying server side validations. I'm not getting how did it bypass the validations

Comment: @user2839497 well, it might be that your server side validations does not work. We are not oracles, we can not possibly know what is going on in your system.

Answer (score 2):

`70.39.61.42`
This is a IP address of someone who sent a request to your server

`[12/Jul/2015:17:05:12 +0000]`

This is a date when perpetrator did it

`"POST /user/register/javascript.void(0)/index.php?do=/user/register/ HTTP/1.1"`

This explains POST request was sent to your server to given URL

302 - This is a status code of the response - HTTP 302

398 - Indicates the size of the response sent

`"http://www.mywebsite.com/user/register/javascript.void(0)"`

This is a URL address of where the perpetrator came from

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
```

This is the user agent of the visitor.